# Calling type(Foo()) results in "<class foo.foo.Foo>" - How to only get "<class foo.Foo>"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a directory structure like:

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
```

In `__init__.py`:

```
from .foo import Foo
```

in `foo.py`:

```
class Foo:
    pass
```

If I build this package and then import it, I see that `foo` is duplicated if I use the `type` command:

```
>>> from foo import Foo
>>> f = Foo()
>>> type(f)
<class 'foo.foo.Foo'>
```

Is it possible to force it such that it instead prints:

```
<class 'foo.Foo'>
```

Comment: You have two levels of importing, that corresponds to `foo.foo`.

Comment: Why does it matter? It's just a string representation of the class object, and not something you should ever be displaying in actual program.